# DbRef with Mongoose - mongoose-dbref or populate?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have the following 2 schemas:

Company Event:

```
var companyEventSchema = new Schema({
    name : String,
    description
    date : Date,
    attendees : [ { type : Schema.ObjectId, ref : 'Member' } ],
]});
```

And Member

```
var memberSchema = new Schema({
    name : String,
    emailAddress: String,
    password :String,
    created: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});
```

Is the way i've ref'd Member from companyEventSchema correct?
I'm trying to do something a long the lines of a dbref.

I saw theres a separate project for that though... [mongoose-dbref](https://github.com/goulash1971/mongoose-dbref)

However, the mongoose docs say the above provides "dbref like functionality"

Which would be more efficient?

Comment: Everything looks good, but remember, that `ref : 'Member'` will only work if later you load that schema to mongoose model with the following : `member = mongoose.model('Member', memberSchema)`. I've been using populate, since I discovered mongoose-dbref gives to me the same result!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You only need to use an actual [`DBRef`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/database-references/#dbrefs) (and `mongoose-dbref`) for the case where a field can contain ObjectIds that reference documents in potentially more than one collection.  A `DBRef` is a tuple of an `ObjectId`, a collection name, and an optional database name.

Mongoose `ref:` fields, however, contain just an `ObjectId` and it's the Mongoose schema that defines what **one** collection the ObjectIds reference.

So Mongoose `ref:` fields are more efficient and should always be used unless you need the multi-collection reference support that `DBRef` provides.