# How can I store data other than ObjectId using Mongoose populate?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Taking the example from here

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

If I try to tweak it so that 'fans' also contains a rating

```
var db = require('houselib/db');
var Schema = db.Schema;
var mongoose = db.mongoose;

var PersonSchema = new Schema({
    name    : String
    , age     : Number
    , stories : [{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Story' }]
});

var StorySchema = new Schema({
    _creator : { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Person' }
    , title    : String
    , fans     : [{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Person', rating: Number}]
});

var Story  = mongoose.model('Story', StorySchema);
var Person = mongoose.model('Person', PersonSchema);

var aaron = new Person({ name: 'Aaron', age: 100 });

aaron.save(function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;

  var story1 = new Story({
      title: "A man who cooked Nintendo"
    , _creator: aaron._id
    , fans: [{type: aaron._id, rating: 4}]
  });

  story1.save(function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
        Story
        .find({ _creator: aaron._id })
        .populate('_creator') // <-- not really necessary
        .run(function (err, stories) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log('The stories JSON is an array: ', stories);
        })
  });

})
```

I get the following error

> CastError: Cast to undefined failed for value "[object Object]"

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says that manual linking is preferred over DBRef

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Database+References#DatabaseReferences-SimpleDirect%2FManualLinking

Comment: See the accepted answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10148308/dbref-with-mongoose-mongoose-dbref-or-populate. Mongoose populate does not use DBRef.

Answer (score 0):

`story.fans` is an array of objectids. objectids do cannot have ratings. You need to add the rating to the Person schema instead of the story schema.

```
var PersonSchema = new Schema({
    name    : String
    , age     : Number
    , rating: Number
    , stories : [{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Story' }]
});
```

Comment: But a person does not have a rating.  A fan gives a rating to a particular story.  I think DBRef is not the right way and manual linking is the way to go