# Mongoose fails to load or save DBRefs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a user document with a DBRef to a company document with the following structure:

[image: DBREF]

As you can see in the image it has the type "Reference" and the value is:
DBRef("Company", ObjectId("5867a193dfa4d653a2fd1a8b"))

**Issue1.** When I fetch the document, Ii doesn't return the companyId field. See model below:
[image: Mongoose model]

**Issue 2.** Another issue I have is when I try to save a user mongoose only saves it as an ObjectId and not as a DBRef.

Anyone know how to fix the issues?

Edit: I use mongodb v3.2.11 and mongoose v4.7.6

Comment: Please avoid [posting images as code](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/) as images can't be copied and pasted into an editor and compiled in order to reproduce the problem. Among many other reasons why it's not generally recommended to post images of code here on SO, images are large and hard to read on mobile devices, they can't be searched and therefore aren't useful to future readers.

Comment: Issue 1: Use [`populate`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html). Issue 2: An ObjectId *is* a reference.

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10148308/dbref-with-mongoose-mongoose-dbref-or-populate

Comment: I understand the importance of writing code, but it's not really code, it's a schema and data and that has no value being searchable. But thanks for the link.

Comment: populate is great, but doesn't really solve my issue. There are several applications interacting with the database and the database enforces validation by itself, so I'm not able to change the type from DBRef to ObjectId.