# Mongo db entity relationship implementation using Spring data

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-mvc, entity-relationship, spring-data-mongodb

I am learning **Spring with Mongo DB** and I'm feeling difficulty in learning the entity-relationship model.
Can anyone teach me how can I implement the following design?

Person collection
A **person** class

- id
- name
- List of the sports object

**Sport** collection
A Sport class

- id (Auto-generated)
- sport name

while I am saving the person class which contains sports class, Sports entity should be saved in Sports collection if it is not already present and Person entity should be stored in Person collection with Sports objects Reference.

While I am retrieving Person class, associated sports class should be fetched from the corresponding collection.
I have tried with **@DBRef** and it is not worked for me.
It will be very helpful if anyone teaches me this scenario or giving the reference to learning this concept.

Very thanks in advance.

Comment: try this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10148308/dbref-with-mongoose-mongoose-dbref-or-populate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> while I am saving the person class which contains sports class, Sports entity should be saved in Sports collection if it is not already present and Person entity should be stored in Person collection with Sports objects Reference.

In `Spring-data-mongo` cascade save not supported. Therefore referencing object will not be saved to the database automatically. To achieve the same you have two option.
1) First, save sports collection (if that record not found in the collection) then save the reference of sports to person collection.
2) Make you custom cascade save implementation. For reference see [this](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/11/spring-data-mongodb-cascade-save-on-dbref-objects.html).

Comment: Kindly share any reference if you have for doing "save the reference of sports to person collection."